# How to test this angular method with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have the following method in my angular controller.  Note that the Upload.upload method is within the apply method.

```
$scope.apply = function () {
    $scope.validationErrors.reset();

    if ($scope.firstName.trim() === '') {
        $scope.validationErrors.firstName = 'First name is required.';
    }

    if ($scope.validationErrors.isValid()){

        Upload.upload({
            url: '/apply',
            fields: {
                'first_name': $scope.firstName,
                'last_name': $scope.lastName
            },
            file: $scope.localFile,
            fileName: $scope.filename
        }).success(function(data){
            if (data === 'successfully saved application'){
                $location.path('/thanks/' + $scope.jobId);
            }else{
                $scope.errorMessage = 'Woops, something went wrong with your application. ' + data;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I can't figure out how to test the success portion of the method. This is what I have so far but it throws an error on the scope.apply() line saying success is undefined.

```
describe('apply calls the uploader upload method', function () {
    var upload;
    var returnMessage = 'successfully saved application';
    var deferred;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, $http, $q, Upload) {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        upload = Upload;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        httpBackend.when('POST', '/apply').respond(returnMessage);
        $controller('ApplyController', {
            $scope: scope,
            $routeParams: { id: 1 },
            $http: $http,
            $q: $q,
            Upload: Upload,
            jobService: jobService
        });
        spyOn(upload, 'upload').and.returnValue(deferred);
    }));

    it('calls the Upload upload method', function () {
        scope.firstName = scope.lastName = scope.phoneNumber = scope.zipCode = scope.filename = 'test';
        scope.jobId = 1;
        scope.emailAddress = 'test@test.com';
        scope.apply();
        expect(upload.upload).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

How can I test the success portion of this method?  Thanks.

Comment: you will have to do $httpBackend.flush() to get the mocked http response/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do $httpBackend.flush() to get the mocked http response. Assuming everything else is correct, the below test should pass. See more information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

```
it('calls the Upload upload method', function () {
        scope.firstName = scope.lastName = scope.phoneNumber = scope.zipCode = scope.filename = 'test';
        scope.jobId = 1;
        scope.emailAddress = 'test@test.com';
        scope.apply();
        httpBackend.flush();
        expect(upload.upload).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Aside:- after each test verify that all of the requests defined via the expect api were made and also that there are no outstanding requests that need to be flushed.

```
afterEach(function() {
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
   });
```

EDIT: 
Spotted another issue. When setting up the spy, you should return deferred.promise and not deferred. Try this:-

```
spyOn(upload, 'upload').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
```

If this also doesn't work, could you share a plunker for this?

Comment: Thank you but even after adding that I still get the same error - 'undefined is not a function ...Upload.upload(....).success

Comment: I have updated the answer. See if it helps. If not, could you share a plunker for this?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not.  And I'm not quite sure how to put together a plunker for the whole app along with tests.  I ended up writing a different kind of test that didn't worry about the success method but instead tested the location.path or scope.errorMessage which is actually the functionality that really needed tested in the end.  That worked, so I'll stick with that.  Thanks again.